# Multiple type for class attribute

Tags: java, android, json

I'm developing an Android app that connects to a webserver which return responses in JSON format. This responses have this format:

```
{status:int, result:mixed}
```

result variable can be boolean, integer, string or array key-value of this types.

I have created Connection class to establish communication with the server. In this class I store status value in an attribute and I want to store result value in another attribute, but my problem is the tretating of this multiple types.

Attributes I have in Connection class are:

```
private String url = "http://url_of_data/";
private String method = null; //Method to execute in server
private Param[] parameters; //Parameters
private boolean get; //True = GET; False = POST
private boolean status; //True = Successful connection; False = Failed
private ??? result;  //This is the type I need to solve!
private String message; //Server message if connection fails
...
...
public ??? getResult () {return this.result;}
```

Is possible to treat result attribute as many formats or I need to find another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

private Object result;

result = 1;

result = false;

result = "ex";   .....

Make use of 'instanceof', when you use 'result'.

```
if ( result instanceof String) {
   //
}
```